# Expose a numpy array as a C++ vector

Tags: c++, numpy, vector

Using `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`, it is easy to expose a `std::vector` as a numpy array. I am now trying to do the opposite: expose a numpy array as a c++ vector.

Exposing as a C array is possible:

```c
// get the size
npy_intp s = PyArray_SIZE(numpy_array);
// get the pointer to the array
bool* c_array = (bool*) PyArray_GETPTR1( numpy_array, 0 );
// Do something
for(unsigned int i=0; i<s; i++)
    c_array[i] = ... ;
```

**Now how about a c++ vector instead of a c array?**

EDIT: I do not wish to copy the data, otherwise the answer is trivial.

Comment: you could just simply construct a new vector using the array as initializer...

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius, I edited the question to specify that I do not wish to copy the data. Only "expose" it. For instance, I might want to modify one element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to just copy the data into a `std::vector`, you might find [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) useful.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numpy_array_{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    const auto s = numpy_array_.size();
    auto arr = numpy_array_.data();

    // ...

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
        arr[i] += 10;

    const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v(arr, arr + s);
    void f(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>&);
    f(v);

    return 0;
}

void f(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>& v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v[i] += 100;
}
```

Notice that the `std::vector` is `const` so that the size can't be changed; this keeps the C-style array as the "master".

Of course, you can easily just copy the data into `std::vector<>` too:

```
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + s);
```

... and even copy it back again (assuming same size or smaller) if necessary

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.begin()+s, arr);
```

Finally, note that [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is special and won't work like a normal C-style array.

Comment: you start off with a vector... for a proper example you should start off with an array ;)

Comment: Does using the `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper>`  will need not to copy all the `bool` (8bits)  but each `bool*` (64bits) making this answer worse than copying the whole bool vector?